# Remove borders between div

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML page -

```
<body>
<div class="blue" ></div>
<div style="padding-bottom: 0; margin-bottom: 0; display: inline-block" >
<div class="yellow"  style="border-right: none" ></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="yellow"></div>
</div> 
<div class="green"></div>  
</body>
```

The css -

```
.blue{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 800;
    height: 100
}
.yellow{
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 150;
    height: 400;
    display:inline-block;
border-right: 0;
    border-bottom: none;

}

.red{
    background-color: red ;
    width: 500;
    height: 400;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
.green{
    background-color: green;
    width: 800;
    height: 100;
border-bottom:2px solid black;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-top: none; 
}
```

How can I remove the borders between the yellow div and the red?
I need the the box will be without internal borders.
(All the div box will be close.

Comment: This code is a mess to be honest, there are spacing issues, missing `;` - tidy it up and make a fiddle then we can see it in action and hopefully help with your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 150px;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="yellow" style="border-right: none"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="yellow"></div>
</div>
<div class="green"></div>
```

I just add display: flex on parent element of yellow and red. Instead of inline-block

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
.blue{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 800;
    height: 100
}
.yellow{
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 150;
    height: 400;
    display:inline-block;
    border-right: 0;
    border-bottom: none;

}

.red{
    background-color: red ;
    width: 500;
    height: 400;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
.green{
    background-color: green;
    width: 800;
    height: 100;
border-bottom:2px solid black;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-top: none; 
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="blue" ></div>
<div style="padding-bottom: 0; margin-bottom: 0; display: inline-block; font-size:0;" >
<div class="yellow"  style="border-right: none; font-size:0;" ></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="yellow"></div>
</div> 
<div class="green"></div>  
</body>
```

I've added font-size:0. It is a workaround.

Comment: No i didn't look again (:

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet...

```css
.blue{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
   border:1px solid #000;
  border-bottom:none;
  margin-top: -3px;
}
.yellow{
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 150px;
    height: 400px;
    display:inline-block;
   border:1px solid #000;
  border-bottom:none;
    border-top:none;
margin-top: -3px;

}

.red{
    background-color: red ;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    border:1px solid #000;
  border-bottom:none;
    border-top:none;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.green{
    background-color: green;
    width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
    border-bottom:2px solid black;
    margin-top: -3px;
    padding: 0;
     border:1px solid #000;
    border-top:none;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="blue" ></div>
<div style="padding-bottom: 0; margin-bottom: 0; display: inline-block" >
<div class="yellow"  style="border-right: none" ></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="yellow" style="border-right: none"></div>
</div> 
<div class="green"></div>  
</body
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "`<!-- -->`" to prevent this issue.

```
<div>
  <div class="yellow"></div><!-- @whitespace
--><div class="red"></div><!-- @whitespace
--><div class="yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use flexbox like this:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="blue" ></div>
<div class="flexbox" >
<div class="yellow"  style="border-right: none" ></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="yellow"></div>
</div> 
<div class="green"></div>  
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.blue{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 800;
    height: 100
}
.yellow{
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 150;
    height: 400;
border-right: 0;
    border-bottom: none;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;

}

.red{
    background-color: red ;
    width: 500;
    height: 400;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
}
.green{
    background-color: green;
    width: 800;
    height: 100;
border-bottom:2px solid black;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-top: none; 
}

.flexbox {
  display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using "inline-block" there will be white-spaces. This can be overcome using -ve margin or have no space between each element.

```css
  .blue {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 800;
  height: 100
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 150;
  height: 400;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500;
  height: 400;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
  width: 800;
  height: 100;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="blue">Blue</div>
  <div style="padding-bottom: 0; margin-bottom: 0; display: inline-block">
    <div class="yellow" style="border-right: none">Yellow</div><div class="red">Red</div><div class="yellow">Yellow</div>
  </div>
  <div class="green">Green</div>
</body>
```

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/o26prsf9/

More explanation can be found here:
https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

You can try as suggested above by using "display:flex" or you can make some changes in CSS as mentioned below:

HTML changes:

```
<div class="blue" ></div>
<div style="padding-bottom: 0; margin-bottom: 0; **display:block;height:400px;**" >
<div class="yellow" ></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="yellow"></div>
</div><div class="green"></div>
```

CSS changes:

```
.blue{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
}
.yellow{
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 150px;
    **height: 100%;**
    display:inline-block;
    border-right: 0px;
    border-bottom: none;
    **float:left;**
}

.red{
    background-color: red ;
    width: 500px;
    **height: 100%;**
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    **float:left;**
}
.green{
    background-color: green;
    width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
border-bottom:2px solid black;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-top: none; 
}
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/wuzjkb3h/

Answer (score -1):

another way is commenting every end of `div` just like this:

```
<body>
<div class="blue" ></div>
<div style="padding-bottom: 0; margin-bottom: 0; display: inline-block" >
<div class="yellow"  style="border-right: none" ></div><!-- a 
--><div class="red"></div><!-- 
--><div class="yellow"></div>
</div> 
<div class="green"></div>  
</body>
```

i put a comment after `yellow`  and close it before `red`.